# How to account for both spatial and temporal autocorrelation at the same in lme?

Tags: nlme, autoregressive-models, autocorrelation, linearmodels

I would like to know how to account for both spatila and temporal autocorrelation at the same time using autoregressive models by lme() function.

To account for the spatial autocorrelation, I use corSpher

```
model_temp<-lme(Y~X1+Year,
                  random=~1|Plot,
                  cor=corSpher(form=~Long+Lat|Plot), data)
```

To account for the temporal autocorrelation, I use corCAR1

```
model_spat<-lme(Y~X1+Year,
                  random=~1|Plot,
                  corCAR1(form=~Year|Plot), data)
```

How could I mix these two models to account for both types of autocorrelation?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you ever come up with a solution for this problem? I have a very analogous one (space + depth, rather than space + time) and a solution to this would likely apply to my situation. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/514976/how-can-i-account-for-autocorrelation-in-location-and-seawater-depth-together-in

Comment: You have interesting data. I haven't found an exact solution for this by lme, but I was also adviced that including latitude and longitude (and their interaction) in GAM could work.